# Simple explanation of how to use commands with a button click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a starter and I'm trying to use commands instead of Click="Display".

```
<Button Content ="Click Me!" Command = "{Binding ClickMeCommand}" />
```

How would I write the method to use the command? Say I want to display a message like "clicked!" in the console when the button is clicked. I'm looking for the simplest implementation that is easy to understand please. I've tried looking at tutorials but they over complicate things and it is hard for me to understand.

Comment: google it, you can find it on your own,

Comment: Yaser that comment sounds kind of rude (even if it's true ;) ). I highly recommend reading the official documentation before actually starting with WPF. A good start regarding commands would be: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One way would be like this:
Create your ViewModel :

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }

    private ICommand clickMeCommand;
    public ICommand ClickMeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (clickMeCommand == null)
                clickMeCommand = new RelayCommand(i => this.ClickMe(), null);
            return clickMeCommand;
        }
    }

    private void ClickMe()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Clicked Me");
    }
}
```

Or initialize it in the constructor.

First paramater of the Command is the method that will be executed when you click the button you binded your command to. The second parameter is the method that enables/disables the button based on the logic. If you would like the button to be enabled at all times just set:

In your MainWindow code behind set the MainViewModel as the datacontext of your mainwindow.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

And the RelayCommand class(this is just an implementation of the ICommand Interface). You can use other implementation of ICommand if you want.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeDelegate, Predicate<object> canExecuteDelegate)
    {
        execute = executeDelegate;
        canExecute = canExecuteDelegate;
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
    }

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've tried that and I keep getting this error: `BindingExpression path error: 'ClickMeCommand' property not found on 'object' ''Task' (HashCode=7438838)'. BindingExpression:Path=ClickMeCommand; DataItem='Task' (HashCode=7438838); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

Comment: Edit: Am I supposed to set DataContext of the Button somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that in a separate project and that worked. However, for my project, I have a Tab Control that has a ListView. This ListView has two columns, one for my object "Task" and one for the button. When I get DataContext, I'm getting Task. Do you know how I would work around this?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the button in inside a DataTemplate.

Comment: You've asked for a simple explanation. I suggest you ask a new question and add all the relevant details and code.